# Error compiling

Tags: hyperref

I updated MiKTeX about a fortnight ago, but I'm now having problems trying to compile.  For some reason, it doesn't like the [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package.  Miktex tells me the following:
[image]

I've allowed the package to install, but there is no output!

I've removed hyperref from my packages, but this interferes with other things in the document I need a hyperlink for!
Is anyone able to shed any light on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how miktex packaging is supposed to work but a recent change (last week) made hyperref.cfg  obsolete and it was removed from miktex and texlive.

Comment: Try if it helps if you update the package database  (menu tasks). Do it in user and admin mode.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since I can't comment on this question, I will use the answer part.

I faced the same issue after updating MikTeX two days ago. I couldn't compile any document anymore, because like @bbujeya I need Hyperref in those documents.

First thing I did was to deinstall MikTeX-Latex, run update package database, run both refreshes and then reinstall MiKTeX-Latex again. Running those commands in Admin mode alone doesn't work.

The issue was solved by @Ulrike Fischer suggestion. After running package update in User mode as well as Admin mode the issue was solved.